# EncodeAndMuxTest.java: Video output with black screen when drawing texture

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-mediacodec

I'm encoding a video using this example [EncodeAndMuxTest.java](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt).
 Instead of generate surface frame by GLES20.glScissor(), i'm drawing a texture (by GLES20.glActiveTexture(), GLES20.glBindTexture(), GLES20.glDrawElements()). But the output video always having black screen.
I recogize that the output video only display color in GLES20.glClear() and it doesn't display image texture. I guess that having some problem with texture when using EGL14.eglSwapBuffers but i cann't figure it out. 
Please kindly help me solve my problem. Thanks so much!

**Update** Code use for example

```
public void testEncodeVideoToMp4() {
    // QVGA at 2Mbps
    mWidth = 320;
    mHeight = 240;
    mBitRate = 2000000;

    try {
        prepareEncoder();
        setupTexture();     // insert new function to setup opengles
        mInputSurface.makeCurrent();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FRAMES; i++) {
        drainEncoder(false);
        // Generate a new frame of input.
        // generateSurfaceFrame(i);
        drawTexture();  // insert new function to draw texture
        mInputSurface.setPresentationTime(computePresentationTimeNsec(i));
        if (VERBOSE)
            Log.d(TAG, "sending frame " + i + " to encoder");
        mInputSurface.swapBuffers();
        }
    drainEncoder(true);
    } finally {
        releaseEncoder();
    }
}
```

setupTexture() function:

```
    public void setupTexture() {

    mVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVerticesData.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mVertices.put(mVerticesData).position(0);
    mIndices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mIndicesData.length * 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
    mIndices.put(mIndicesData).position(0);

    String vShaderStr = "attribute vec4 a_position;   \n"
            + "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;   \n"
            + "varying vec2 v_texCoord;     \n"
            + "void main()                  \n"
            + "{                            \n"
            + "   gl_Position = a_position; \n"
            + "   v_texCoord = a_texCoord;  \n"
            + "}                            \n";

    String fShaderStr = "precision mediump float;                            \n"
            + "varying vec2 v_texCoord;                            \n"
            + "uniform sampler2D s_baseMap;                        \n"
            + "void main()                                         \n"
            + "{                                                   \n"
            + "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_baseMap, v_texCoord );   \n"
            + "}                                                   \n";

    // Load the shaders and get a linked program object
    mProgramObject = ESShader.loadProgram(vShaderStr, fShaderStr);

    // Get the attribute locations
    mPositionLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "a_position");
    mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "a_texCoord");

    // Get the sampler locations
    mBaseMapLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "s_baseMap");

    // Load the texture
    mBaseMapTexId = loadTexture();

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, 720, 1280);
}
```

loadTexture() function

```
private int loadTexture() {
int[] textureId = new int[1];
Bitmap bitmap;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFilePath);   // please change mFilePath to image file in sdcard
if (bitmap == null) {
    return -1;
}

GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureId, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0]);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
bitmap.recycle();
return textureId[0];
```

}

drawTexture() function:

```
    public void drawTexture() {

    GLES20.glClearColor(TEST_R0 / 255.0f, TEST_G0 / 255.0f, TEST_B0 / 255.0f, 1.0f); // green color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use the program object
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramObject);

    // Load the vertex position
    mVertices.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionLoc, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, mVertices);
    // Load the texture coordinate
    mVertices.position(3);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, mVertices);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionLoc);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

    // Bind the base map
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mBaseMapTexId);

    // Set the base map sampler to texture unit to 0
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mBaseMapLoc, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices);
}
```

Variables use for openGL ES

```
    // Handle to a program object
private int mProgramObject;

// Attribute locations
private int mPositionLoc;
private int mTexCoordLoc;

// Sampler location
private int mBaseMapLoc;
// Texture handle
private int mBaseMapTexId;

// Additional member variables
private FloatBuffer mVertices;
private ShortBuffer mIndices;

private final float[] mVerticesData = { -1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 0
        0.0f, 0.0f, // TexCoord 0
        -1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 1
        0.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 1
        1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 2
        1.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 2
        1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 3
        1.0f, 0.0f // TexCoord 3
};

private final short[] mIndicesData = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
```

And the video output only display [green screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9WeRbvLh8y1ZFNROVdpTW92M1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: could you add the code to your question?

Comment: Dear, i updated code and screenshot output video!

Comment: The "green screen" is what you'd likely get if you didn't draw anything -- YUV 0,0,0 looks like that.  You can find a more complete example of GL recording in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika); see the "record GL app" activity.  Other activities render textured triangles (where the source is either a generated texture or camera input) using the same library of GLES routines.

Comment: @fadden I've a similar code and I'm too facing the same problem. It's the same I found on the learning opengl tutorials (http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/). Can you please elaborate what's the problem?